# How to load users and usergroups info and poliocis from openid connect provider?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have configured the nifi to authenticate via openid connect(clicl cloack) provider and i would like to know how to configure nifi to load the groups info,policies defined in the openid provider? if nifi supports this feature, i can only see in documentation that nifi can load using ldap or kerberos authentication providers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently NiFi only supports OIDC for authentication, and groups and policies are part of authorization.

NiFi's Authorizer has a UserGroupProvider and an AccessPolicyProvider. For the UserGroupProvider there is file-based or LDAP, and for the AccessPolicyProvider there is file-based or Ranger.

There would need to be OpenID Connect implementations of these two components in order to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks bryan, you are right  and  i didn't seen any implementations for those Providers